# Fixing Table_locks_waited is high in MySQL

Tags: database, phpmyadmin, mysql, database-administration

When I'm looking at info of my database I see the following. Table_locks_waited is high. How do I go about mitigating this problem?

[image]

Comment: What is the specific problem? I think you should ignore phpmyadmin unless there is a problem which is affecting your users. (NB: I also think you should erase phpmyadmin from your hard drive forever)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you should run:

```
 show status like '%\_locks\_%';
```

This will show you the ratio of queries that wait to those that are able to get locks immediately.  Probably you have a higher mix of writes to reads, that is causing mysql to have to wait more frequently than is optimum, but overall performance can't be analyzed with a single statistic.

My first suggestion would be to alter your tables so that you are using the Innodb engine for the tables that are bearing the brunt of the transaction load.  Innodb has row locking rather than table locking, and also has clustered indexes and query data caching that tend to improve performance in many cases.